# Can someone explain to me why this wont run?

Tags: javascript, html, class, object

im supposed to create a class, then use the class to create a new object with the same properties, display them, change the price, and then display the new information. Im so confused. I dont even know where im going wrong at.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function Television(manufac, scrnSize, retPrice) {
       myTV.manufacturer = manufac
       myTV.diagScrnSize = scrnSize
       myTV.retailPrice = retPrice
       myTV.setPrice = setPrice()
       myTV.displayInfo = displayInfo()
    };
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Display function
        function displayInfo() {
        document.write("Manufacturer:  + myTV.manufacturer + BR");
        document.write("Screen Diagonal Size:  + myTV.diagonalSize + BR");
        document.write("Retail Price: + myTV.retailPrice + BR");
        document.write("Thank you!");
    };
    // Set price function
        function setPrice() {
        p = parsefloat(p);
        this.retailPrice = setPrice;
    };
       function displayInfo() {
        document.write("Manufacturer:  + myTV.manufacturer + BR");
        document.write("Screen Diagonal Size:  + myTV.diagonalSize + BR");
        document.write("Retail Price: + myTV.retailPrice + BR");
        document.write("Thank you!");
        };
        var BR = "<br />"
        var myTV = new Television("Sony", 52, 1299.00);

    // Run the program
        myTV.displayInfo()
        myTV.setPrice() 
        myTV.displayInfo()
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What have you done to debug the problem? What exactly is the issue?

Comment: `myTV` is undefined inside your `Television` function. It won't  inherit from something that is not defined yet.

Comment: I recommend to have a look at a JS tutorial, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide or http://eloquentjavascript.net/. There are a couple of things wrong in your code: You are referring to undeclared or uninitialized variables. You don't seem to know how `this` works. You are not using string concatenation correctly.

Comment: Change `myTV` to `this` inside of your `Television` function.

Comment: Stay away from `document.write()`.

Comment: i changed myTV to this inside my Television function. Ive been working on this for two days an havent gotten anywhere. From my understanding heres the steps.

Comment: @PHPglue first: create the class and give it its properties,  2nd: create the method(s). In the case of this program theres two which is to display the information about the TV , change the price AFTER displaying the orginal information of the class, and then redisplaying the info. Its really not that complicated im just not understanding where im going wrong whem it appears (to me) to look like it should besides a few mistakes one as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You have quite a few errors in there. Compare yours to this to see where you went wrong.

```js
function Television(manufac, scrnSize, retPrice) {
  this.manufacturer = manufac;
  this.diagScrnSize = scrnSize;
  this.retailPrice = retPrice;
  this.setPrice = function(p){
    p = parseFloat(p);
    this.retailPrice = p;
  }
  this.displayInfo = function(){
        document.write("Manufacturer:"  + myTV.manufacturer + BR);
        document.write("Screen Diagonal Size:"  + myTV.diagScrnSize + BR);
        document.write("Retail Price:" + myTV.retailPrice + BR);
        document.write("Thank you!" + BR);
    
  };
};
var BR = "<br />";
var myTV = new Television("Sony", 52, 1299.00);
myTV.displayInfo();
myTV.setPrice(1099.00);
myTV.displayInfo();
```

Make sure you define the display function. I just see a comment, no declaration